# Docker build failing with command not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel6

My `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
  FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel6.7
  USER root
  MAINTAINER zaman L
  RUN mkdir /apps
  COPY httpd-2.4.34.tar.bz2 /tmp
  RUN /usr/bin/tar xjvf /tmp/httpd-2.4.34.tar.bz2 -C /apps
  VOLUME /tmp
  VOLUME /apps
```

But `docker build` is failing with this error:

```
  `Step 7 : RUN /usr/bin/tar xjvf /tmp/httpd-2.4.34.tar.bz2 -C /apps
   ---> Running in 541bdd63aac6
  /bin/sh: /usr/bin/tar: No such file or directory
  The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/tar xjvf /tmp/httpd-2.4.34.tar.bz2 -C /apps' returned a non-zero code: 127`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace /usr/bin/tar to tar and retry. I believe the  binary path might be different .

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because it can't find your `tar` executable in `/usr/bin/tar`.

A couple things you can do:

- Replace `/usr/bin/tar` with `tar`, as mentioned in a comment.
- Run `which tar` to see where your `tar` executable lives, and replace `/usr/bin/tar` with the output from that command.

Either of those should work - the first is more general (i.e. won't break if your `tar` executable ends up somewhere different later on), but the second won't start using a different executable if a `tar` is found earlier in your `PATH` search.

Comment: Is it still saying "No such file or directory", or is the error different?

Comment: No such file or directory .. I even tried wit RUN which tar but it is showing "/bin/sh: which: command not found"

Comment: It works when I add `yum install tar` in Dockerfile . So seems tar is not installed by default in the RHEL image I am using